# Copy Variable Value into Script Block

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

Consider the following

```
$y = 'foo'
$x = {
    write-host $y
}

powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "$x"
```

This will not print foo, but I'd like it to. Is there a way to force powershell to inline these variables?

Comment: This looks like an X-Y problem to me. What are you trying to achieve with this? Do you need to run the scriptblock as a separate process? Why?

Comment: Because DSC Script Resources are broken as hell and don't function correctly unless you run them in separate processes.

Answer (score 0):

One option:

```
$y = 'foo'
$x = [scriptblock]::Create("Write-Host $y")

powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "$x"
```

Comment: For that solution you do.  By using an expandable string you create the script block with all the local variables already expanded.

Comment: IMHO, it's not so much a matter of treating it as a string as recognizing that because it's a cmd executable argument, it is a string.